# How to run "ant update" in Hybris with only "Update Running System"?

Tags: java, deployment, ant, devops, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to run `ant update` from the command line after building my Hybris project but it runs **Update Running System**, **Clear hMC Configuration from Database**, **Create essential data** and **Localize type** (please refer the following image):

[image: hybris console screen]

Is there a way to run `ant update` command from command line so that it will only select "**Update Running System**"?

What parameter can I pass with `ant update` to only run "**Update Running System**" and not any other options?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the command `-DconfigFile=<your file>` :

Example:

```
ant updatesystem -Dtenant=<my tenant> -DconfigFile=path/to/my/config.json
```

And here is an example of the config.json

```
{
  "init": "Go",
  "initmethod": "update",
  "clearhmc": "true",
  "essential": "true",
  "localizetypes": "true",
  "solrfacetsearch_sample": "true",
  "hmc_sample": "true",
  "solrfacetsearchhmc_sample": "true",
  "customerreview_sample": "true",
  "voucher_sample": "true",
  "promotions_sample": "true",
  "basecommerce_sample": "true",
  "cms2_sample": "true",
  "cms2lib_sample": "true",
  "ticketsystem_sample": "true",
  "payment_sample": "true",
  "btg_sample": "true",
  "platformhmc_sample": "true",
  "commerceservices_sample": "true",
  "commercewebservicescommons_sample": "true",
  "acceleratorservices_sample": "true",
  "acceleratorcms_sample": "true",
  "yacceleratorfulfilmentprocess_sample": "true",
  "yacceleratorcore_sample": "true",
 ....
  "electronicsstore_importCoreData": [
    "yes"
  ],
  "electronicsstore_importSampleData": [
    "yes"
  ],
  "electronicsstore_activateSolrCronJobs": [
    "yes"
  ],
  "yacceleratortest_createTestData": [
    "yes"
  ],
  "yacceleratorcockpits_importCustomReports": [
    "yes"
  ]
}
```

As you can see, it's not so easy to implement this file. As suggested in [Initializing and Updating SAP Hybris Commerce](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/2011/en-US/8bf4f76d86691014a29cf03f0616bdb7.html), go to the HAC once, do your configuration in the webpage and click on <kbd>Dump configuration</kbd>. It will give you the generated json file.

Answer (score 2):

Try with ant `ant updatesystem` . 
To see the list of possible commands(targets) you can write `ant -p` . There you can find more about the commands.

Answer (score 2):

> ant updatesystem [-Dtenant=tenantID -DdryRun=true|false
>   -DtypeSystemOnly=true|false -DconfigFile=PATH_TO_CONFIG_FILE]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this command to update the system without importing any impexes.

```
ant updatesystem -DtypeSystemOnly=true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the system with an ant updatesystem and don't import impexes during build you can only use the property `update.importEssentialData.enabled=false` and put it into your `local.properties` file.