# How to include patches in hybris with ant updatesystem?

Tags: java, deployment, configuration, ant, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to automate the hac update of Hybris via commandline with `ant updatesystem`.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888290/how-to-run-ant-update-in-hybris-with-only-update-running-system) question i found out, i could automate the "hac update" based on a config file.

I was able to create such a file by using the "Dump configuration" button in the hac.
However i want to import some patches, too. Unfortunately all my patches are explicitly listed with an ID.

```
{
  "init": "Go",
  "initmethod": "update",
  "localizetypes": "true",
  "mypatches_sample": "true",
  [...]
  "patch_mypatches": [
    "ae2dbba4cbb3fc5b0c374f1717533d8f",
    "67acedd074c6e4af0e09624aee71ca3a",
    "188b121a90671ca65088260a391708c5",
    "b622ef7314e68822b7bf9d6a5b20358d"
  ],
  "filteredPatches": "true"
}
```

How can i edit the config file to always use all available patches? [SAP help page](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1811/en-US/08c89599782a4d589a2d5651899d02f1.html) just shows how to create a config file via the dump button...

I tired to set patch_mypatches to "true" or "all" with no effect. I also marked a patch as required. But as long as i don't define the patch ids no patch will be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found the [solution](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12767723/urs-execute-all-patches-per-default.html) for this Problem:

Instead of adding `"patch_mypatches": [...]` and `"filteredPatches":"true"`

i just had to add `"patches": "true"`

For example:

```
{
  "init": "Go",
  "initmethod": "update",
  "localizetypes": "true",
  "mypatches_sample": "true",
  [...]
  "patches": "true"
}
```

Now all patches are applied when executing `ant updatesystem -DconfigFile=conf.json`

Comment: Interesting information. I didn't know this existed